# Display/Hide <p:notificationBar > with the same shortcut <p:hotkey>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to hide / show  the shortcut `<p:hotkey>` , I succeeded to hide it in jQuery code and `<p:hotkey>` , How can I use the same key to display it ?

```
  <script>
          jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
               $(window).click(function () {
                                         PF('bar').hide();
                                           });
                $(window).blur(function () {
                 PF('bar').hide();
                                           });
                                              });
     </script>
```

xhtml :

```
<p:notificationBar autoDisplay="true"  position="top" effect="slide" widgetVar="bar"   style="z-index: 1500;opacity: .98">  
                    <center>
                        <h:outputText value="Select Bank and press Ctrl , + to add agency" style="color:red;font-size:14px;" /><br/><br/>
                        <h:outputText value="Click anywhere or press SPACE to hide this bar" style="color:red;font-size:14px;" />
                    </center> 
                </p:notificationBar>
                <p:hotkey bind="space"  onsuccess="PF('bar').hide()"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
bar.toggel();
```

It should work